# "Service Temporarily Unavailable" I got this error when I launched my project from netbeans

Tags: java, openshift, netbeans-8

When I launched my project through netbeans on OpenShift cloud I got this error:

```
Service Temporarily Unavailable

The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) Server at prosol-prosol7845.rhcloud.com Port 80
```

and when I have executed "rhc tail -a prosol", I got this:

[image]

For launching it from netbeans I am following this procedure:

1. Clone the repository from openshift cloud.
2. Develop a project and clean and build it.
3. Then, commit and push the changes to the cloud.
4. Change the server to OpenShift by Red Hat.
5. Then execute or run the project.

What should I do to avoid this error? 
Please help me it's my final year project.

Comment: Maybe complete logs would show more than the screenshot above. You can ssh into your app and find them in `~/app-root/logs/`. If you don't find the root cause there, I recommend sharing the logs using a service like pastebin rather than posting directly in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get your development workflow, so I suggest this:

1. Clone the repository from openshift
2. Develop a project and clean and build it.
3. Then, open up your terminal and type `git add .`, then `git commit -m "Some relevant message"` then `git push origin master`.

That's all you need to do to deploy your app. I recommend reading through the [Getting Started](https://developers.openshift.com/en/getting-started-windows.html) and following a couple of links there to learn more about the development process on OpenShift